# Почта для домена

Tags: php

Где взять хорошую почту для домена?

Comment: конкретизируйте вопрос: что именно нужно - веб интерфейс? сервисы, предоставляющие размещение почты в своем домене на их сервере?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подойдёт **любая** почта, повторяю **любая**, просто в настройках включите функцию "Свой домен" и настройте и тем-более почти везде эта функция подключается бесплатно.

Answer (score 2):

[Почта для домена](https://pdd.yandex.ru/domains_add/) от Yandex - это хороший качественный бесплатный продукт:

- подключается элементарно (нужно прописать записи в DNS),
- не требует обслуживания (Yandex сам все решает),
- в большинстве случаев совершенно бесплатно.

Рекомендую.